# Need to create a local user with admin and then 4-6 random characters at the end

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Hi i need to create a local user on several servers that starts with admin and then has a random 4 characters at the end.

This is what I have so far in Powershell

```
$usr = "admin" 

$rand = New-Object System.Random

$admin = $usr + [char]$rand.next(33,127) + [char]$rand.next(33,127) + [char]$rand.next(33,127) + [char]$rand.next(33,127)
```

This works, but it includes special characters which are not allowed in usernames so fails when it uses one. Does anyone know how I can stop this from using special characters or give me another idea on how I could achieve this.

Powershell syntax would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When calling the `$rand.Next()` method, you can use the numbers `(97,122)` this will only return characters from a to z.

Comment: thanks will test and let you know. just for my info how do the numbers = the different a-z characters ?

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/
you will see the decimal number and it's char representation.